# Is it possible to upgrade my Desktop all in one processor

Tags: window

My PC is desktop all in one lenovo c340 series , i have 3rd gen i3 processor change to 3rd i5 processor quad core

Comment: This question shows very little research or effort. I didn't do the -1, but I'm going to guess that's why someone else did

Answer (score 3):

According to the [service manual](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_c340c440_hmm_20130114.pdf) you can replace the CPU, and the system board has an Intel H61 chipset which supports [these CPUs.](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_%28chipsets%29/H61_Express.html)

The BIOS may refuse to boot with any CPU other than the exact type that is in it now, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the processor. The system has a **LGA1155 Socket** which supports **Intel 3rd Gen Core i5 3 i5-3330S / 2.7 GHz Quad-Core**

To Know how to replace the processor refer pg.no. "53" on the following pdf
[lenovo_c340c440_hmm_20130114.pdf](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/desktop_pub/lenovo_c340c440_hmm_20130114.pdf)